# select tag get disappeared while storing jsp variable inside javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm storing the query result inside JavaScript variable, I used JSP to fetch data from database,

so I declared one JSP string variable to store record. and I'm assigning that variable to JavaScript variable.

```
var opt="";
<%
  String sdm="", smg="",sname="",s1="kkk";    
  sql="SELECT DISTINCT(BFM_Name) FROM BarsFeeMaster ORDER BY BFM_Name";
  Statement stmt11 = connection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs11 =stmt11.executeQuery(sql); 
  while(rs11.next()) 
  {
     sname=rs11.getString("BFM_Name");
%>
  opt+="<option value='<%=sname%>'>abc</option>";
<%  
  }
%>
```

Here same is not accessible, in sense when I used this code my select tag get disappeared.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate a bit more than that if you want an answer. As it is, your question is impossible to answer. Adn in fact, you don't even have a question.

Comment: hey JB, i used this code to fillup select box dynamically. all option i m fetching from database. and later i m appending this string to select tag.

Comment: That's still not a question, and you still don't explain what happens, when, etc. If it's a JSP problem, look at the generated HTML code. If it's a JS problem, use a JS debugger like Firebug.

Comment: if i used opt+="<option value='<%=s1%>'>abc</option>"; then it will displaying value kkk but when i use sname then only, select box getting disappeared.

Comment: means javascript function is not working

Comment: Then, show us at least the code of the JS function. The *generated* code. The one you find when you do "View Page Source" in your browser. Tell us what this function is supposed to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

(String)rs11.getobject() in value field

Comment: i try but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var opt="";
<%
  String sdm="", smg="",sname="",s1="kkk";    
  sql="SELECT DISTINCT(BFM_Name) FROM BarsFeeMaster ORDER BY BFM_Name";
  Statement stmt11 = connection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs11 =stmt11.executeQuery(sql); 
  while(rs11.next()) 
  {
     sname=rs11.getString("BFM_Name");
%>
  opt+="<option value='"<%=sname%>"'>abc</option>";
<%  
  }
%>
```

Greetings.

Comment: thanks for reply. but its mistakes in entering the value. i enter sname field value after enter key so when we are dynamically filling option na that time its not possible if value containt enter key.but in static create option tag then there is not porblem.so thats why that error comes.ones again thanks for reply.